# What is the fastest way to remove adhesive from ceramic tile?

Tags: tile, cleaning, adhesive

What is the fastest way to remove adhesive from the ceramic tile?

I have no patience for removing the adhesive by using an utility knife.

Comment: probably a grout saw, but you still have't specified what adhesive you want to remove from where

Comment: From my experience, DIYing requires patience. :P